# Can't replace 0 to nan in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with only 1 column. I want to replace all '0' to np.nan but I can't achieve that.

dataframe is called area.
I tried:

```
area.replace(0,np.nan)
area.replace(to_replace=0,np.nan)
area.replace(to_replace=0,value=np.nan)

area.replace('0',np.nan)
```

What should I do?

Comment: You have to assign it back to the variable after calling `replace()`.

Comment: or use `area.replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can set `inplace` to `True` (default is `False`):

```
area.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

See examples in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace).

Answer (score 13):

You need to do:

```
area = area.replace(0, np.nan)
```